# Make Github Repository private but want to show public message

Tags: github, repository, project

I have a public repository in Github. Recently, I made it private to do major work on the project. However, I want to show a message such as "The project is under construction" so people can wait for major change. Now, after making the repo private, the URL tells "404 page not found..." How to show a public message or readme at the same time keeping the repo private. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would:

- keep the repository public
- change the README to indicate the project is under construction
- create a separate private repository, based on the history of the public one
- go on working on the private repository;

Once the major work is ready, I would push back to the public (frozen) repository.